# Latent Dirichlet allocation Implementation

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, topic-models, c++

I'm looking for some LDA implementation. I know about this one, [MALLET](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/) but it is coded in Java and I need some more performant.

Can someone give me some reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [original C++ code](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/lda-c/) of the LDA inventors Blei et al.

Also quite fast is [GibbsLDA](http://gibbslda.sourceforge.net/) (written in C and C++).

If you want to parallelize it you might want to check out [plda](http://code.google.com/p/plda/) (C++).

Comment: I will just add one more, Yahoo!LDA - https://github.com/shravanmn/Yahoo_LDA